# How can I update cell value of a data table?

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, datatable

How can I update cell value of data table

```
if ((sr_no == "") && (customer_name != ""))
{
  string contact_no = SheetData.Tables[0].Rows[row].ItemArray[3].ToString();
  Records.Rows[0].ItemArray[2]                                      
}
```

I want to update cell of datatable if contact_no fround in next row.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

if `Records` is your `DataTable` do this:

```
Records.Rows[i][j] = value;
```

this does not answer the whole question but shows you how to set a value in a DataTable "cell".

you are using the `ItemArray` which is not needed because once you have the right Row you can simply access its columns withh `[]`

you can elaborate more and find out the final solution based on this hint.

Comment: This work only if Records.Columns[column].ReadOnly = false;

Answer (score 13):

If you use `Records.Rows[0].ItemArray[2] = value` this won't work, but if you use `Records.Rows[0][2] = value` this works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

When using DataTables version 1.10.22, the previous answers did not work for me, but the following did work.  If `Records` is the DataTable, `r` is the zero-based row index, and `c` is the zero-based column index, then:

```
    Record.cell( r, c ).data( value ).draw();
```

Calling `draw()` at the end of the chain is optional, but forces the DataTable to update its internal caches.

Answer (score 0):

for a specific column of all rows, (2 ==> column index (3rd column))

```
table.column(2).data().each( function ( value, index) {
        table.cell(index, 2).data('update data');
}); table.draw();
```