# How to find and replace the country column in Excel using c#?

Tags: c#

How can I modify the below function to replace "USA" with "United States" in c#?

```
SmartXLS.WorkBook WB = new WorkBook();
WB.readXLSX(filename);
DataTable dt = WB.ExportDataTable();
// var from = "USA";
//var to = "United States";
//loop through each row

foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
{
    var cmp = new Company();
    cmp.company_type = dr[0].ToString();
    cmp.company_category = dr[2].ToString();
    cmp.name = dr[3].ToString();
    cmp.url = dr[4].ToString();
    cmp.telephone = dr[5].ToString();
    //cmp.address.address3 = dr[6].ToString();
    cmp.description= dr[15].ToString();
    MicroCompanies.Add(cmp);
    //Column A = 0 B = 1.....
    //System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(dr[0].ToString());
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate [How can i update cell value of data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309798/how-can-i-update-cell-value-of-data-table)

Comment: If you want to change the excel sheet then edit your question and provide more details. How are you reading the excel file? With openXML? Interop?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Do something like:

```
if (dr[3].ToString() == "United States") {
 dr[3].ToString().Replace("USA", "United States");
 cmp.name = dr[3].ToString();
} else {
 cmp.name = dr[3].ToString();
}
```

Not sure on exact Syntax as don't have VS open