# Reflect any change of the value of a cell in the square matrix in the DataGridView automatically, without the need to manually call any method

Tags: c#, arrays, matrix, events, datagridview

I have a square two-dimensional array (a matrix) and a DataGridView.
The user interacts only with the matrix, by changing the values of the cells.
The only purpose of the DataGridView is to reflect any change of the value in a cell of the matrix. It is absolutely passive. No user interaction occurs with the DataGridView.
The requirement is: Any change of the value in a cell of the matrix must be automatically reflected in the DataGridView, without the need to manually invoke any method.
All the methods that need to be invoked, must be invoked by means of events.
Here is the code I wrote:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The requirement is: Any change of the value in a cell of the matrix must be automatically reflected in the DataGridView,
    /// without the need to manually invoke any method.
    /// All the methods that need to be invoked, must be invoked by means of events.
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<MatrixChangedEventArgs> CellValueChanged;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a new matrix with the specified number of rows and columns.
        _matrix = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        _numberOfRows = _matrix.GetLength(0);
        _numberOfColumns = _matrix.GetLength(1);

        // Create a new DataGridView and customize its properties.
        dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        dataGridView1.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        dataGridView1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F);
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = false; // allow editing of cell values

        // Define columns for the DataGridView.
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + i, "Column" + i);
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].ValueType = typeof(int);
        }

        // Add the specified number of rows to the DataGridView.
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(_numberOfRows);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

        // Bind the matrix data to the DataGridView.
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = _matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private int[,] _matrix;
    private int _numberOfRows;
    private int _numberOfColumns;

    public int this[int row, int col]
    {
        get { return _matrix[row, col]; }
        set
        {
            _matrix[row, col] = value;
            dataGridView1[col, row].Value = value;
            UpdateDataGridView();
        }
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value != null)
        {
            _matrix[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] = (int)dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].Value;
        }
        else
        {
            _matrix[e.RowIndex, e.ColumnIndex] = 0;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateDataGridView()
    {
        // Update the DataGridView with the values in the matrix.
        for (int i = 0; i < _matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = _matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = rnd.Next(0, _numberOfRows);
        int column = rnd.Next(0, _numberOfColumns);
        int value = rnd.Next(1, 101);
        SetMatrixValue(row, column, value);
    }

    private void SetMatrixValue(int row, int column, int value)
    {
        int oldValue = _matrix[row, column];
        _matrix[row, column] = value;
        RaiseMatrixChangedEvent(row, column, oldValue, value);
    }

    private void RaiseMatrixChangedEvent(int row, int column, int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        if (CellValueChanged != null)
        {
            CellValueChanged.Invoke(this, new MatrixChangedEventArgs(row, column, oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }

    public class MatrixChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        private int _row;
        public int Row1
        {
            get { return _row; }
            set { _row = value; }
        }

        private int _column;
        public int Column1
        {
            get { return _column; }
            set { _column = value; }
        }

        private int _oldValue;
        public int OldValue1
        {
            get { return _oldValue; }
            set { _oldValue = value; }
        }

        private int _newValue;
        public int NewValue1
        {
            get { return _newValue; }
            set { _newValue = value; }
        }

        public MatrixChangedEventArgs(int row, int column, int oldValue, int newValue)
        {
            _row = row;
            _column = column;
            _oldValue = oldValue;
            _newValue = newValue;
        }
    }
}
```

}

```
The events are called but the displayed value in the DataGridView does not change.
I do not know what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
```

Comment: What happens if you add the following to _RaiseMatrixChangedEvent_: `else { Debug.WriteLine("Info: This event has no subscribers."); }`?

Comment: @user09938 You are right! That's exactly what happened. How can I change the code in order to subscribe correctly to the event?

Comment: All the code appears to be in the same class. There doesn't seem to be a need for events.

Comment: @user09938 Did you run the code? The DataGridView does not show the value change that occurred in a cell of the matrix. As user 09938 correctly supposed, the subscription to  RaiseMatrixChangedEvent is not correct. The problem is that I do not know how to fix this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below shows how to display a 2D array in a [DataGridView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=windowsdesktop-8.0). I'll show three different options. The first two options are minimal modifications of your existing code.

**Option 1** (without using event) - minimal modification of code in OP

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a new matrix with the specified number of rows and columns.
        _matrix = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        _numberOfRows = _matrix.GetLength(0);
        _numberOfColumns = _matrix.GetLength(1);

        // Create a new DataGridView and customize its properties.
        dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        dataGridView1.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        dataGridView1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F);
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; //don't allow editing of cell values

        // Define columns for the DataGridView.
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + i, "Column" + i);
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].ValueType = typeof(int);
        }

        // Add the specified number of rows to the DataGridView.
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(_numberOfRows);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

        // add matrix data to the DataGridView.
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                //set value
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = _matrix[i, j];
            }
        }
    }

    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private int[,] _matrix;
    private int _numberOfRows;
    private int _numberOfColumns;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = rnd.Next(0, _numberOfRows);
        int column = rnd.Next(0, _numberOfColumns);
        //int value = rnd.Next(1, 101);
        int value = rnd.Next(10, 101);
        SetMatrixValue(row, column, value);
    }

    private void SetMatrixValue(int row, int column, int value)
    {
        int oldValue = _matrix[row, column];
        _matrix[row, column] = value;

        //update value in DataGridView
        dataGridView1[column, row].Value = value;

        Debug.WriteLine($"row: {row} column: {column} oldValue: {oldValue} newValue: {value}");
    }
}
```

---

**Option 2** (using event) - minimal modification of code in OP

**Note**: Using an `event` in this manner is unnecessary. *Option 1* or *Option 3* is preferable.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public event EventHandler<MatrixChangedEventArgs> CellValueChanged;
    Random rnd = new Random();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Create a new matrix with the specified number of rows and columns.
        _matrix = new int[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } };
        _numberOfRows = _matrix.GetLength(0);
        _numberOfColumns = _matrix.GetLength(1);

        // Create a new DataGridView and customize its properties.
        dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
        dataGridView1.Size = new Size(500, 500);
        dataGridView1.Location = new Point(50, 50);
        dataGridView1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F);
        dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
        dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
        dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; // don't allow editing of cell values

        // Define columns for the DataGridView.
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfColumns; i++)
        {
            dataGridView1.Columns.Add("Column" + i, "Column" + i);
            dataGridView1.Columns[i].ValueType = typeof(int);
        }

        // Add the specified number of rows to the DataGridView.
        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(_numberOfRows);
        this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

        // add matrix data to the DataGridView.
        for (int i = 0; i < _numberOfRows; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < _numberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                //set value
                dataGridView1[j, i].Value = _matrix[i, j];
            }
        }

        //subscribe to event
        this.CellValueChanged += Form1_CellValueChanged;
    }

    private void Form1_CellValueChanged(object sender, MatrixChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //update the DataGridView with the values in the matrix.
        dataGridView1[e.Column, e.Row].Value = e.NewValue;

        Debug.WriteLine($"row: {e.Row} column: {e.Column} oldValue: {e.OldValue} newValue: {e.NewValue}");
    }

    private DataGridView dataGridView1;
    private int[,] _matrix;
    private int _numberOfRows;
    private int _numberOfColumns;

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int row = rnd.Next(0, _numberOfRows);
        int column = rnd.Next(0, _numberOfColumns);
        int value = rnd.Next(1, 101);
        SetMatrixValue(row, column, value);
    }

    private void SetMatrixValue(int row, int column, int value)
    {
        int oldValue = _matrix[row, column];
        _matrix[row, column] = value;

        //raise event
        RaiseMatrixChangedEvent(row, column, oldValue, value);
    }

    private void RaiseMatrixChangedEvent(int row, int column, int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        if (CellValueChanged != null)
        {
            CellValueChanged.Invoke(this, new MatrixChangedEventArgs(row, column, oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }
}
```

---

**Option 3**:

**Create a new `Windows Forms App (.NET Framework)` project** (name: MatrixTest)

**Create a class** (name: MatrixChangedEventArgs.cs)

```
public class MatrixChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int Row { get; private set; }
    public int Column { get; private set; }
    public int OldValue { get; private set; }
    public int NewValue { get; private set; }   

    public MatrixChangedEventArgs(int row, int column, int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        Row = row;
        Column = column;
        OldValue = oldValue;
        NewValue = newValue;
    }
}
```

**Create a class** (name: Helper.cs)

```
public class Helper
{
    //event
    public event EventHandler<MatrixChangedEventArgs> CellValueChanged;

    public int[,] Matrix { get; private set; } = null;

    public int NumberOfColumns
    {
        get
        {
            if (Matrix != null)
                return Matrix.GetLength(1);
            else
                return 0;
        }
    }
    public int NumberOfRows
    {
        get 
        { 
            if (Matrix != null) 
                return Matrix.GetLength(0); 
            else 
                return 0; 
        }
    }
  
    public Helper(int[,] matrix)
    {
        Matrix = matrix;
    }

    private void OnCellValueChanged(int row, int column, int oldValue, int newValue)
    {
        if (CellValueChanged != null)
        {
            //raise event
            CellValueChanged.Invoke(this, new MatrixChangedEventArgs(row, column, oldValue, newValue));
        }
    }

    public void SetMatrixValue(int row, int column, int newValue)
    {
        int oldValue = Matrix[row, column];
        Matrix[row, column] = newValue;

        //raise event
        OnCellValueChanged(row, column, oldValue, newValue);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        string output = string.Empty;

        for (int i = 0; i < Matrix.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < Matrix.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                output += $"[{i},{j}]: { Matrix[i, j]} {System.Environment.NewLine}";
            }
        }

        return output;
    }
}
```

---

**Form1.cs** (size: 816, 544)

- Open **Solution Explorer** (View => Solution Explorer)
- Right-click **Form1.cs**
- Select **View Designer**
- Open **Properties Window** (View => Properties Window)
- Change form **Size** to **816, 544**

**Form1.cs**:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace MatrixTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private DataGridView dataGridView1;
        private Helper _helper = null;
        private Random _rnd = new Random();

        private Button button1 = null;
        private StatusStrip statusStrip1 = null;
        private ToolStripStatusLabel toolStripStatusLabel1 = null;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            // create a new matrix with the specified number of rows and columns.
            _helper = new Helper(new int[3, 3] { { 1, 2, 3 }, { 4, 5, 6 }, { 7, 8, 9 } });

            //subscribe to event
            _helper.CellValueChanged += Helper_CellValueChanged;

            button1 = new Button();
            button1.Name = "button1";
            button1.Size = new Size(50, 30);
            button1.Location = new Point(70, 10);
            button1.Text = "Test";

            //add
            this.Controls.Add(button1);

            //subscribe
            button1.Click += Button1_Click;

            // Create a new DataGridView and customize its properties.
            dataGridView1 = new DataGridView();
            dataGridView1.Name = "dataGridView1";
            dataGridView1.Size = new Size(675, 400);
            dataGridView1.Location = new Point(70, 50);
            //dataGridView1.Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 15.75F);

            //set properties
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToAddRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AllowUserToDeleteRows = false;
            dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
            dataGridView1.AutoSizeColumnsMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnsMode.Fill;
            dataGridView1.BackgroundColor = System.Drawing.SystemColors.Control;
            dataGridView1.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.RowHeadersVisible = false;
            dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true;

            // Define columns for the DataGridView.
            for (int j = 0; j < _helper.NumberOfColumns; j++)
            {
                DataGridViewTextBoxColumn col = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn()
                {
                    AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill,
                    DataPropertyName = $"col{j.ToString()}",
                    DefaultCellStyle = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter },
                    FillWeight = 10,
                    HeaderCell = new DataGridViewColumnHeaderCell() { Style = new DataGridViewCellStyle() { Alignment = DataGridViewContentAlignment.MiddleCenter, Font = new Font("Times New Roman", 10F, FontStyle.Bold) } },
                    HeaderText = j.ToString(),
                    MinimumWidth = 5,
                    Name = $"col{j.ToString()}",
                    ReadOnly = true,
                    Width = 10
                };

                //add column to DataGridView
                dataGridView1.Columns.Add(col);
            }

            // Add the specified number of rows to the DataGridView.
            dataGridView1.Rows.Add(_helper.NumberOfRows);

            //add to form
            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView1);

            Debug.WriteLine($"_helper.NumberOfRows: {_helper.NumberOfRows} _helper.NumberOfColumns: {_helper.NumberOfColumns}");

            // add matrix data to the DataGridView.
            for (int i = 0; i < _helper.NumberOfRows; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < _helper.NumberOfColumns; j++)
                {
                    dataGridView1[j, i].Value = _helper.Matrix[i, j];
                }
            }

            //ToolStripStatusLabel - create new instance
            toolStripStatusLabel1 = new ToolStripStatusLabel();
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Name = "toolStripStatusLabel1";
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(118, 17);
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = "Status:";

            //StatusStrip - create new instance
            statusStrip1 = new StatusStrip();
            statusStrip1.Name = "statusStrip1";
            statusStrip1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, this.Size.Height - 60);
            statusStrip1.Size = new Size(this.Width - 16, 22);
            statusStrip1.Text = "statusStrip1";

            //add ToolStripStatusLabel to StatusStrip
            statusStrip1.Items.AddRange(new System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem[] { toolStripStatusLabel1 });

            //add
            this.Controls.Add(statusStrip1);
        }

        private void Helper_CellValueChanged(object sender, MatrixChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            //update value
            dataGridView1[e.Column, e.Row].Value = e.NewValue;

            string msg = $"Updated row: {e.Row} column: {e.Column} OldValue: '{e.OldValue}' NewValue: '{e.NewValue}'";

            //set value 
            toolStripStatusLabel1.Text = msg;
            statusStrip1.Refresh();

            Debug.WriteLine(msg);
        }

        private void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int row = _rnd.Next(0, _helper.NumberOfRows);
            int column = _rnd.Next(0, _helper.NumberOfColumns);
            int value = _rnd.Next(10, 101);

            //set value
            _helper.SetMatrixValue(row, column, value);
        }
    }
}
```

---

Here's a demo:

[image]

---

**Additional Resources**:

- [DataColumn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datacolumn?view=net-7.0)
- [How can I update cell value of a data table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28628697/10024425)
- [Multidimensional Arrays (C# Programming Guide)](https://Multidimensional%20Arrays%20(C#%20Programming%20Guide))
- [Random.Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random.next?view=net-8.0)
- [String interpolation using $](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated)

Comment: I do not know what is not clear. The requirement is written in the beginning of the code I posted.
The content of the matrix is displayed in the DataGridView by my code all right! Probably you did not run it. The problem is that when I change the value of a cell in the matrix, this change is not reflected in the DataGridView. As user09938 pointed out, the problem is with the subscription to the MatrixChangedEvent, but I do not know how to fix it. I do not want new code. I only wish I new how to fix mine.

Comment: @user2102327: I've re-written the post.

Comment: Thank you very much for the time and effort.
Option 1 works very well.